OR_BIBED_11 error in Google Pay API after Google approving web integration (not android)
I have this button integrated in a Prestashop which was working correctly at the test stage:
Integrated Gpay button
Even if my integration has been production approved, the Gpay popup throws me this error:
Gpay error
The only information I have about OR_BIBED_11 is what appears in the Google Pay's troubleshooting documentation:
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/support/troubleshooting
How is this possible?
I have tried to re-approve the integration. Also I've verified that the keys used are correct.

Okay... In the moment I posted the question I've realized that a blankspace was mistakenly typed at the merchant id section...
